# coin toss smooth transition

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to make an app similar to this one.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cointoss/id287965865?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

What I can't get for the life of me is how is this app able to make the coin rotate fast initially and then slow down and then show the heads/tails.

I have already sudo coded my app to work. What I got are two images for a quater,

- heads
- tails
- I am able to generate a random number
- make a flip using CATransition animation with KCaMedaTimingFunctionLinear
- Tranistion my uiimage background to heads/tails till I reach my random number

What I can't figure out is how does this app make it look soo real? They must be using multiple images (inbetween rotation). My coin rotation just looks clumbsy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you I assume are trying to use UIImage view or something like that to create this effect. You will not be able to do this without a huge amount of work.

In the Coin Toss app they are using OpenGL to render the coin. They have create a 3D model of a coin and then mapped textures to it. Then just rotated the model in 3D space using OpenGL.

If you want something similar with the same performance you will also need to use this!

I know having to go through and learn something new for things like this is a pain, but OpenGL is really powerful. Here is a link to a really good uxorial that I used to get started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial

Is well worth going through this before you use OpenGL in a project!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks George. Yup, I was using uiimage to do the work and it wasn't looking that great. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: When you say it can be doing using uiimages with a lot of work, what do you mean by it? Do I need to create multiple images of the coin in various states of rotation?

Comment: Yeah, you would need either a lot of images to flip between. Or you could have a video of the coin flip, and play it back on loop changing the speed of playback. Or you could do some nifty transforms on your UImageViews. However, none of these would give you smooth performance and UIView animations are not well optimised. The only way you will be able to get anything close to the quality of the Coin Toss app is to use OpenGL.

Comment: you can use 20 images to get the same effect.10 for one side and 10 for the other.You can bend the coin using illustrator so that you get the shadow effects an so on automatically done.but as george says the best and most efficient way to use OpenGL.